# Why am I getting this error message "Cannot find module '@reduxjs/toolkit' or its corresponding type declarations"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am fairly familiar with React-Redux but I am trying to practice including TS now as well. I am using the suggested method of creating a new project from the react-redux team for creating a TS project

"npx degit reduxjs/redux-templates/packages/vite-template-redux my-app"

That being said, from the get go I get this error message [image]

I have never seen this error before with any of my other React-Redux projects until I added TS to it. I created this project a few different ways as well and I still get the same message. I have been reading about this online and found that it has something to do with the dependencies and the config files.

```
This is my tsconfig.json file.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",   // I have tried node, and node16 as well
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vite/client"],    // This was vitest/globals, because it had and error   
    "baseUrl": "./",             // I added the baseUrl, and the paths information 
    "paths": {                   // but it still doesn't help
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"],     // I added this, but it doesn't seem to do anything
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

This is my tsconfig.node.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",    // I tried this as node as well
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

This is my vite.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config"    // This also has an issue
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"        // And this one too, cannot find module

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    open: true,
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: "src/setupTests",
    mockReset: true,
  },
  resolve: {          //I added the resolve and alias hoping it would help
    alias: {
      '@' : './src/*', 
    },
  },
})

This is package.json

{
  "name": "vite-template-redux",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest run",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.2.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.47",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "jsdom": "^23.2.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.11",
    "vitest": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but, can you try `npm install @types/react-redux`? In my case, That error usually occurred when I didn't install typescript package.